# Display multiple adminForm's in joomla

Tags: forms, joomla

When creating a custom view in joomla with multiple forms, there is a conflict because each form has the `id="adminForm" name="adminForm"`.

Renaming the form causes incompatibility with joomla.

How can I display multiple adminForm's on a single view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Restructure the form elements into a single page-encompassing form
   and remove the `&task=controller.task` portion from the form action
   URL, e.g.

   > ```
   > <form 
   >   action="<?php echo JRoute::_(''); ?>" 
   >   name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="form-validate" 
   >   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   > ```
2. On each submit button use the joomla method: `onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('controller.task')"` e.g.

   > ```
   > <button type="submit"
   >   onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('group.join')">Join</button>
   > ```
3. Joomla will automatically update a hidden field with the `name="task"` and `value="controller.task"` which will get submitted with the form.
   You need to have this element in your form for it to work, e.g.

   > ```
   > <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
   > </form>
   > ```